# how can I update a vue child-component from the vuex-store

Tags: vue.js, promise, fetch, vuex

My application shows a window where player can enter name and passcode to enter

When the player exists and has a card, I want to show the card as well.
When the player exists, I make the card visible. Then in 'created'I call fetchSpelerCards. This is successful but shows in the VUE console as pending...

I hope some experienced vue user reads this and can help me with a hint, reference or explanation.

For that I have in  the following code:

```
 <h2>Meld je aan</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="register" class="mb-3"> 
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" placeholder="naam" v-model="name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control m-2" placeholder="kies inlogcode" v-model="pass_code">     
        </div>

        <button type="submit" @click="checkSpeler()"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="color:white">Save</button>
    </form>
    <p class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errorMessage !== ''"> {{errorMessage}} </p>
    <p class="alert alert-success" v-if="successMessage !== ''"> {{successMessage}} </p>
    <CardsSpeler v-if="spelerCorrect"></CardsSpeler>
    
</div>
</template>
```

The  component looks as follows:

```
 <h2>Cards 1</h2>
    <form @submit.prevent="addCard" class="mb-3"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title" v-model="card.title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea  class="form-control" placeholder="description" v-model="card.description">
            </textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" ref="fileUpload" id="file_picture_input">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="color:white">Save</button>
    </form>
    <div class="card card-body mb-2" v-for="card in cards" v-bind:key="card.id">   
        <h3> {{currentSpelerCard.title}}   </h3>
        <p> {{currentSpelerCard.description}}</p>
        <img class="img-circle" style="width:150px" v-bind:src="currentSpelerCard.picture" alt="Card Image">


    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    mounted(){
        console.log('component mounted');  
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState([
        'currentSpeler' ,'currentSpelerCard'
        ]), 
    },
    data() {
        return{
            cardExists:false,
            successMessage:'',
            errorMessage:'',
        }

    },
    created(){
      this.fetchSpelerCards();
    },
    methods: {

        ...mapActions([  'getGames', 'addGame', 'fetchSpelerCards'  ]),

        fetchSpelerCards(){
            
                this.$store.dispatch('fetchSpelerCards', this.currentSpeler.speler.id )
                .then(res => { 
                    this.cardExists = true;
                    this.successMessage = res;
                    console.log(res);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.errorMessage = err;
                    this.cardExists = false;
                });
            
        },
```

The corresponding action, in actions.js is:

```
export const fetchSpelerCards = ({commit}, speler_id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {     
        let status = '';
        let data ={};
        fetch(`api/cardsBySpeler/${speler_id}`)
        .then(res => {
            status = res.status;
            data = res.json(); 
        })
        .then(res=>{
            if ( status === 200) {
                commit('SET_PLAYER_CARD', data);
                resolve('Kaart gevonden');
            }
            else {
                reject('Er is geen kaart beschikbaar')
            }
        });
    })
}
```

In the vuex-store I see (viewed with VUE add-on of chrome browser):

```
currentSpelerCard: Promise
```

Yet, the response of the fetch command was successful, and the card was pulled in, as I see also in the console: status 200, I can see name, title, image address etc..

I was under the assumption that, when the promise eventually resolves, the store is updated and the card becomes available because of the:

```
computed: {  ...mapState([  'currentSpeler' ,'currentSpelerCard' ]),
```

Can anyone help me and explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please use https://codesandbox.io/ for a sandbox  project so we can debug.

Comment: Could you share the mutation code that change `currentSpelerCard`?

Answer (score 1):

`fetchSpelerCards` in Vuex commits `SET_PLAYER_CARD` with `data`, this will be a pending promise. You need to await the promise.

You can solve this in a few different ways.

Making the function `async` and `await res.json()` would be the easiest.

```js
...
  fetch(`api/cardsBySpeler/${speler_id}`)
    .then(async res => {
      status = res.status;
      data = await res.json(); 
    })
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
This worked.

I just do not understand why this is necessary. In the original script I commit in a .then()-function, so I expect this to happen only after the promise is resolved. 

Where am I wrong, what do I miss here?